# How to select a value from a span dropdown

Tags: selenium

I have been trying to select the "all" value from this dropdown, but I was only able to open/click the dropdown but not select the option all..

Getting this message in selenium - org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

[Html image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOeqa.png)

This is my code..

```
//Select Items per page dropdown//
@FindBy(xpath="//\"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/span[1]/span/span/span[2]/span")
private WebElement itemsPerPageDropdown;

public void selectAllItemsInDropdown(){
    Select itemsPerPage=new Select(itemsPerPageDropdown);
    itemsPerPage.selectByValue("all");}

public void selectItemsPerPageDropdown() {
    itemsPerPageDropdown.click();

}
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. HTML is considered code.

Comment: Your XPath string is incorrectly formatted. It has 3 quotes... is that a typo or is that your actual code?

Comment: Hi, can you share your website link here so that we can give exact relative xpath (Your xpath is wrong in your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@FindBy(xpath="//select[@data-role='dropdownlist']")
private WebElement itemsPerPageDropdown;
```

Try to use the xpath to select tag , select class can be used only with select tag.

For other drop down you have to do:

click dropdown menu and then wait for visibility of dropdown item you want to click:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[something]"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[something]"))).click();
```

Comment: @JustinLambert mine was also having a typo updated it thanks :)